# Adding plane in between edges/vertices

Tags: modeling, objects

I am new to blender so I have very basic question.
I have made a contour of my desired shape, but there was some extra vertices i did not need so I deleted them, but after deleting them the plane i had there disappeared too. So how do I place the plane back in between my selected edges? [image]

My second question is concerned about very similar problem of mine. How do I connect these selected edges to finish the shape of my shoe?
[image]

Comment: (Shortcuts) You can select four vertices in vertex mode [1] and make a face [f].

Answer (score 2):

The solution of your problem is to Fill the empty space , in edit mode select all vertices and do <kbd>F</kbd> to fill your space , please try to ignore filling Obtuse angles shapes coz they can cause many topology problem